# Haskell list comprehension with two variables

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am trying to find some special numbers such that when it is divided by 2 gives 1, divided by 3 gives 2 and so on upto 6.

This perfectly works.

```
[ x | x <- [1..1000],x `mod` 2 == 1 , x `mod` 3 == 2 , x `mod` 4 == 3 , x `mod` 5 == 4 , x `mod` 6 == 5]
```

Ans:

```
[59,119,179,239,299,359,419,479,539,599,659,719,779,839,899,959]
```

I am trying to make it better so that it is not too verbose but the following doesn't work.

```
[ x | x <- [1..1000], y <- [2..6], x `mod` y == (y-1) ]
```

It takes all x for which *any* of the y satisfies the condition but what I want is, I want x which satisfies the condition for *all* y.

Comment: alternate solution hint: these numbers are also congruent to -1 modulo 2,3,4,5,and 6.

Comment: Hint: try using the `all` function

Comment: Do you know of the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the condition as

```
[ x | x <- [1..1000], all (\y -> x `mod` y == y-1) [2 .. 6]]
```

But you can do better in this specific case,

```
let modulus = foldl1 lcm [2 .. 6]
[x | x <- [1 .. 1000], x `mod` modulus == modulus - 1]
[modulus - 1, 2*modulus - 1 .. 1000]  -- even better
```

Answer (score 3):

List comprehension is short, but often obscure. It is often easier to write/read monadic code. Let's translate first version

```
do
x <- [1..1000] -- here a value is selected
guard $ x `mod` 2 == 1  -- it checked
guard $ x `mod` 3 == 2 -- and checked
guard $ x `mod` 4 == 3 
guard $ x `mod` 5 == 4 
guard $ x `mod` 6 == 5 -- you got the point
return x -- value returned
```

and second is

```
do
x <- [1..1000] -- value selected
y <- [2..6]  -- another value selected
guard $ x `mod` y == (y-1) -- the pair of previously selected values is checked 
return x -- and now the first value returned.
```

===

second written correct:

```
do
x <- [1..1000]
guard $ and $ do
              y <- [2..6] 
              return $ x `mod` y == 1
return x
```

it can be rewritten in many ways, including

```
[x | x <- [1..1000], and [x `mod` y == 1 | y <- [2..6] ] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, you may still "recover" the solution from your second attempt:

```
import Data.List

map head $ filter ((==5).length) $ group [ x | x <- [1..1000], y <- [2..6], x `mod` y == (y-1) ]
```